# Passing method name as a callback VS. wrapping it with annoymous function

Tags: javascript, callback

I have a button #test.

```
var obj = {
  name: "John",
  test: function() {
    console.log('name '+ this.name );
  }
};

$("#test").on( "click", obj.test);
```

This will log an empty string (logging typeof this.name gives a string).

Edit:  I understand *this* context becomes the button, hence this.name returns nothing.

Versus

```
var obj = {
  name: "John",
  test: function() {
    console.log('name '+ this.name );
  }
};

$("#test").on( "click", function() {
  obj.test();  //logs John
});
```

What is the difference?

Edit: How does wrapping obj.test() with an annon function make it behave differently than above?

Comment: This isn't a "closures" question. Tag removed.

Comment: I think it is.  The second example uses a closure which makes it behave differently than the first example.

Comment: Nope, it's about the resolution of `this`. There is no closure in either example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's about resolving `this`. If you use `$("#test").on("click", obj.test);` then `this` will be the button but if you pass a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) then `this` will be `obj`.

When I call obj.test then `this` in test will be obj.

JQuery will set `this` to be the button when it's clicked so passing obj.test without a reference to obj being `this` will break your obj.test function.

The best way to resolve this problem is to use [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (you need the [polyfil](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility) for IE < 9):

```
var obj = {
    name: "John",
    test: function () {
        console.log('This is:' + this.toString());
    },
    toString: function () {
        return "It's test"
    }
};

$("#test").on("click", function () {
    // by the way; this here is the button
    console.log("what's this here:", this.toString());
    obj.test();  //works but creates a closure
});

$("#test").on("click", obj.test);//breaks, this will be button in test

$("#test").on("click", obj.test.bind(obj));//works

// now to show how this is resolved
window.mytest = obj.test;
window.mytest();// this is window
var obj2 = {
    toString: function () {
        return "this is obj2";
    }
};
obj2.test = obj.test;
obj2.test();//this is obj2
```

Answer (score 1):

The real difference is what object test is operating on. When you call the function in the second example you are calling the function with the obj context. In the first example you are passing a reference to the function but not the context that it was attached to. In the first case when the function is called it is actually operating the the global scope.

To test this out try putting:
var name = "eiriki"; somewhere in global scope then running your function. It will likely print out eiriki unless you have something else assigning to it already.

Comment: I don't think this is true.  The context in the first sample is the button object.

Comment: @eirikrl Hath is correct, jQuery will set `this` to be the button. When you pass a closure then within the closure `this` will still be the button but because you will call `obj.test()` then `this` will be obj within the test function. See my answer for more details.